# open JSON file with Excel Power Query

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

Hi I have the following JSON file format (sample) and please any one let me know how to open the file in excel columns or tables. Thank you.

{ "fields": [ "id", "name", "definition" ], "items": [ { "ref": "#28:1", "id": "1", "values": [ "1", "ABC", "This is file 1." ], "relationships": [ { "toTable": "Table 1", "relationships": [ { "id": "1", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 2", "relationships": [ { "id": "1", "extra": {} }, { "id": "7", "extra": {} }, { "id": "11", "extra": {} }, { "id": "24", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 3", "relationships": [ { "id": "22", "extra": {} }, { "id": "31", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 4", "relationships": [ { "id": "37", "extra": {} }, { "id": "38", "extra": {} }, { "id": "50", "extra": {} } ] } ] }, { "ref": "#28:2", "id": "2", "values": [ "2", "DEF", "This is file 2." ], "relationships": [ { "toTable": "Table 1", "relationships": [ { "id": "3", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 2", "relationships": [ { "id": "1", "extra": {} }, { "id": "5", "extra": {} }, { "id": "24", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 3", "relationships": [ { "id": "1", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 4", "relationships": [ { "id": "5", "extra": {} }, { "id": "7", "extra": {} } ] } ] }, { "ref": "#28:3", "id": "3", "values": [ "3", "GHI", "This is file 3." ], "relationships": [ { "toTable": "Table 1", "relationships": [ { "id": "1", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 2", "relationships": [ { "id": "2", "extra": {} }, { "id": "5", "extra": {} }, { "id": "8", "extra": {} } ] }, { "toTable": "Table 4", "relationships": [ { "id": "5", "extra": {} }, { "id": "8", "extra": {} } ] } ] } ], "relatedObjects": [ { "TableId": "Table 1", "totalItems": 151, "totalHits": 1, "fields": [ "id", "Number", "name" ], "items": [ { "ref": "#165:28", "id": "1", "values": [ "1", "ASRU" ] } ] }, { "TableId": "Table 2", "totalItems": 282, "totalHits": 5, "fields": [ "id", "fullName", "firstName" ], "items": [ { "ref": "#68:83", "id": "5", "values": [ "5", "ABC", "Acer" ] } ] } ] }

Tried excel power query to create reports using the above JSON file format.

Answer (score 0):

spreadsheet view, click the “Data” tab on the ribbon at the top of Excel. In the “Data” sections, “Import and Transform” section, select the product from Get Data > From File > JSON. Open your computer's standard "Import" window. Here, open the width where your JSON file is located.

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, i need to parse properly into columns with related items.